# Styling Muitextfield input background, hides label

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to style Textfield from the global theme, but, I can't manage to put a colored background for the input only (white), whithout hiding the label when it move inside the input.

I want to have this result :
[image]

But, I have this one : [image]
I put the white background with transparency, to show that the text is indeed behind it, but, if I set the transparency to no transparency, the label will be fully hidden behind the white background, like this : [image]

Here is my theme :

```js
export const testGlobal = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    common: {
      black: "#000",
      white: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",

      blue: {
        light: "rgba(184, 244, 255, 1)",
        default: "rgba(0, 219, 255, 1)",
        dark: "rgba(0, 184, 213, 1)",
      },
      red: {
        light: "#ff1744",
        default: "#fd0031",
        dark: "#e3002c",
      },
      orange: {
        light: "#ffc046",
        default: "#ff8f00",
        dark: "#c56000",
      },
      grey: {
        light: "rgba(99, 99, 99, 1)",
        medium: "rgba(99, 99, 99, 1)",
        paper: "rgba(65, 65, 65, 1)",
        default: "rgba(99, 99, 99, 1)",
        dark: "rgba(60, 60, 60, 1)",
      },
    },
  },
});

testGlobal.root = {
  borderColor: "rgba(85, 85, 85, 1)",
};
testGlobal.img = {
  width: "79%",
};
testGlobal.palette = {
  ...testGlobal.palette,
  vumeter: {
    top: "#fd0031",
    mid: "#ff8f00",
    bottom: "rgba(0, 219, 255, 1)",
  },
  playlist: {
    playing: "#ef5350",
  },
  background: {
    light: "rgba(99, 99, 99, 1)",
    medium: "rgba(99, 99, 99, 1)",
    paper: "rgba(65, 65, 65, 1)",
    default: "rgba(99, 99, 99, 1)",
    dark: "rgba(60, 60, 60, 1)",
  },
  primary: {
    light: "rgba(184, 244, 255, 1)",
    main: "rgba(0, 219, 255, 1)",
    dark: "rgba(0, 184, 213, 1)",
    contrastText: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
  },
  text: {
    primary: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87)",
    secondary: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)",
    disabled: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.38)",
    hint: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.38)",
  },
};
testGlobal.overrides = {
  MuiFormLabel: {
    root: {
      background: "black",
      fontWeight: "bolder",
      color: "grey",
      "&.Mui-focused": { color: "grey" },
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
  MuiInput: {
    root: {
      fontWeight: "bolder",
      background: "white", // the white background that keep hiding my label :(
      padding: theme.spacing(1),
      color: "black",
    },

  },
};

testGlobal.props = {
  MuiInput: { disableUnderline: true },
};
```

I did not add additional styling to the textfield component

Why would a background get on top of the label? :(

Comment: Always try to share a working code link.

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful if you could share a working code link on a JavaScript playground site such as [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/), however this sounds like it could be a `z-index` issue. Try to add something such as `position: relative;z-index: 99;` to the label. `z-index` controls the overlapping order on the page so this should work.